# PyQGIS -"invalid data source" when trying to open several .shp files

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, data-source

I have a folder with almost 3000 subfolders, each containing several ESRI shapefiles. I tried to write a script to read each of these files, do some basic analysis on them and store new files in those subfolders. When I ran the script, it goes through folders and after almost 200 successful operations gives me an error (Invalid Data Source). The data source is valid because when I restart the same algorithm (starting from the where it gave error) there is no error and it continues to work for another 200 folders and then gives another error. This way I have to look at the process constantly and restart the process from where it stopped. Any idea that what causes this problem and how I can solve it.

```
# this is a function that designed to get all features including the road network, schools, and # bus stops and divide them and allocate them based on each municipality in the Netherland
# this function works on the basis of city by city
# function inputs
# 1- the main polygon layer represents all the municipalitis
# 2- the main path to store the results
# 3- the municipality admin boundaries
# 4- the municipality boundary with 500 meter buffer
# 5- the main road network (all roads includes)
# 6- the local road network (all roads except highways, primary roads, secondary roads and        # motorways)
# 7- the schools in the whole Netherlands
# 8- the bus stops in the whole Netherlands

# import required modules and libraries
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.analysis import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
import os

# removing all the layers from interface
QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers()

# reading the admin layer
admin_fn= "/home/.../School_Zones/Germany/region1/germany_r1_admin.shp"
admin_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(admin_fn, "admin", "ogr")

# reading the road layer, it is better to check for disconnected islands, Crs 3857
road_fn= "/home/.../School_Zones/Germany/region1/germany_r1_roads.shp"
road_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(road_fn, "roads", "ogr")

# reading the local road layer, the road network without three road types: primary, secondary and motorway
road_local_fn= "/home/.../School_Zones/Germany/region1/germany_r1_local_roads.shp"
road_local_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(road_local_fn, "local roads", "ogr")

# reading the schools layer, shoud be Point, Crs 3857
school_fn = "/home/.../School_Zones/Germany/region1/germany_r1_schools.shp"
school_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(school_fn, "schools", "ogr")

# reading the bus stops layer
bus_stop_fn = "/home/.../School_Zones/Germany/region1/germany_r1_bus_stops.shp"
bus_stop_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(bus_stop_fn, "bus_stops", "ogr")

# this is the main path
main_path = "/home/.../School_Zones/Germany/region1/clipping_results"

#####
def clipping_features(path, feature, school, road, bus, local_road):
   
    # defining clipping layer based on the city clip1
    city_clip_fn = path + '/' + str(feature['city_id']) + '_' + feature['Mun'] + "/municipality_admin.shp"
    city_clip_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(city_clip_fn, feature['Mun'], "ogr")
    
    # defining clipping layer based on the city buffer
    city_buffer_fn = path + '/' + str(feature['city_id']) + '_' + feature['Mun'] + "/municipality_admin_buffer.shp"
    city_buffer_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(city_buffer_fn, feature['Mun'], "ogr")
    
    # clipping the schools, using the city clip layer
    school_clip_params = {'INPUT': school,
                          'OVERLAY': city_clip_layer,
                          'OUTPUT': 'memory' }
    school_clip_result = processing.run("native:clip", school_clip_params)['OUTPUT']
    school_clip_layer = QgsVectorLayer(school_clip_result, "schools", "ogr")
    # write the results and load them on the map
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(school_clip_layer, path + '/' + str(feature['city_id']) + '_' + feature['Mun'] + "/school_points.shp",'utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([school_clip_layer])
    
    # clipping the road network based on the city buffer
    road_clip_params = {'INPUT': road,
                        'OVERLAY': city_buffer_layer,
                        'OUTPUT': 'memory' }
    road_clip_result = processing.run("native:clip", road_clip_params)['OUTPUT']
    road_clip_layer = QgsVectorLayer(road_clip_result, "roads", "ogr")
    # write the results and load them on the map
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(road_clip_layer, path + '/' + str(feature['city_id']) + '_' + feature['Mun'] + "/road_network.shp",'utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([road_clip_layer])
    
    #clipping bus stops based on the city buffer
    bus_clip_params = {'INPUT': bus,
                       'OVERLAY': city_buffer_layer,
                       'OUTPUT': 'memory' }
    bus_clip_result = processing.run("native:clip", bus_clip_params)['OUTPUT']
    bus_clip_layer = QgsVectorLayer(bus_clip_result, "bus stops", "ogr")
    # write the results and load them on the map
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(bus_clip_layer, path + '/' + str(feature['city_id']) + '_' + feature['Mun'] + "/bus_stops.shp",'utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([bus_clip_layer])
    
    # this part is to run clip for local roads 
    local_road_clip_params = {'INPUT': local_road,
                          'OVERLAY': city_buffer_layer,
                          'OUTPUT': 'memory' }
    local_road_clip_result = processing.run("native:clip", local_road_clip_params)['OUTPUT']
    local_road_clip_layer = QgsVectorLayer(local_road_clip_result, "local roads", "ogr")
    # write the results and load them on the map
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(local_road_clip_layer, path + '/' + str(feature['city_id']) + '_' + feature['Mun'] + "/road_network_local.shp",'utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([local_road_clip_layer])
    
           
        # cliping schools


#####
k = 0
start = 0
end = 2850
for fet in admin_layer.getFeatures():
    k = k + 1
    if start < k < end:
        print(k)
        city_name = fet["Mun"]
        print(city_name)
        clipping_features(main_path, fet, school_layer, road_layer, bus_stop_layer, road_local_layer)

print("done!")
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 116, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 66, in clipping_features
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 156, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for OVERLAY: invalid value
Invalid Data Source: /home/.../region1/clipping_results/1902_Landshut/municipality_admin_buffer.shp is not a valid or recognized data source.
```

Comment: `QgsVectorLayer(r'/home/.../region1/clipping_results/1902_Landshut/municipality_admin_buffer.shp').isValid()`?

Comment: @BERA, first time that I face the error is False, when I rerun the script again it becomes True

Comment: I don't know the answer but this idea can be logical: You are calling "iface.addVectorLayer()" for almost 3000 times. This could raise problems if file's size is large. Beside this, you are adding all layers to  QGSProject.instance(). I suggest you to use QgsVectorLayer class. Take a look to docs: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#retrieving-information-about-attributes

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the tips. I have to use QsgVectorLayer() instead of iface.addVectorLayer().